# Property X does not exist on type Y when using static class property

Tags: typescript

I'm having an issue with typescript error when I want to access a static class property in some module.

Let's say that I want to export some class with static property:

```
// MODULE 1
export class AppConfig {
  static readonly apiKey: string = process.env.API_KEY;
}
```

In module 2 I create an Interface for some object;

```
// MODULE 2
import { AppConfig } from "./appConfig";

interface AppContext {
  config: AppConfig;
  ...
}

export default class App {
 ...

 get ctx(): AppContext {
  return {
    config: AppConfig,
    ...
  };
 }

 ...
}
```

In module 3 I finally want to access the property:

```
// MODULE 3
...    
function createContext(app: App): object {
  return Object.assign(app.ctx, {
    apiContext: app.ctx.config.apiKey
  });
}
...
```

And then I get TS ERROR:
*"Property 'apiKey' does not exist on type 'AppConfig'."*, which is quite strange, because the property is undoubtedly on this type.

Answer (score 2):

Static properties are not accessible via class instance. It should be accessed via class identifier like this:

```ts
const key = AppConfig.apiKey;
```

See [Static Properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#static-properties)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the **config** param is declared as an instance of **AppConfig**:

```
config: AppConfig;
```

But it's actually not.

I would suggest thinking about another approach in declaring this param. E.g.:

```
interface IApiKeyProvider {
    apiKey: string;
}

interface AppContext {
  config: IApiKeyProvider;
}
```

Comment: Actually, I had implemented the suggested approach but I thought there should be another way to achieve the desired output without using interfaces. I guess there isn't...